# How to detect mouseup event in a blend4web sensor manifold

Tags: blend4web

Blend4Web's documentation is not really clear how you can detect a mouseup event inside a sensor manifold. At its official forum I find a [suggestion](https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums/topic/267/?page=1#post-1211) to compare the elapsed time against the delta time, which would be highly over convoluted.

Is there any simpler and safer solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully there is a simpler solution. The mouse click sensor passes a `1` to the manifold's logic function on `mousedown` event and a `0` value, when the mouse button is not pressed. So we write a logic function which returns its value inside a [CT_CONTINUOUS](https://www.blend4web.com/api_doc/module-controls.html#.CT_CONTINUOUS) type manifold, which according to the documentation behaves like this:

> Manifold control type: continuous. Such manifold executes the callback
>   with a positive pulse (+1) each frame when the result of evaluation of
>   its logic function is non-zero. It executes a callback with a negative
>   pulse (-1) once the logic function evaluates to zero.

So your callback function will have the `1` pulse on every frame when the mouse is down and the pulse `-1` on the first frame after the mouse button is released.

```
function registerMouse() {
  console.log("mouse registered");
  var clickSensor = m_ctl.create_mouse_click_sensor();

  function logic(triggers) {
   if (triggers[0])
    return 1;
   else
    return 0;
  }

  function cb(obj, id, pulse, param) {
   console.log(pulse);
   return;
  };

  m_ctl.create_sensor_manifold(null,
                               "mouse",
                               m_ctl.CT_CONTINUOUS,
                               [clickSensor],
                               logic,
                               cb,
                               );
 }
```

**Notes**

In this simple example it would be sufficient to use the default logic function (pass null instead of a function), however you should definitely use this scaffolding, when you have multiple sensors in your manifold.

You can also use [CT_TRIGGER](https://www.blend4web.com/api_doc/module-controls.html#.CT_TRIGGER) type manifold